# Bounds on operator 2-norms on partial traces of linearly related operators

Tags: operator-norms, traces, linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras

Consider an arbitary positive semidefinite operator ρ, acting on ℂ<sup>A</sup> ⊗ ℂ<sup>B</sup> ⊗ ℂ<sup>C</sup>, for A,B,C finite. Also, let P be an orthogonal projector on ℂ<sup>B</sup> ⊗ ℂ<sup>C</sup> . For the sake of concision, I will write R = 1<sub>ℂ<sup>A</sup></sub> ⊗ P ; this of course is also an orthogonal projector. Consider the completely positive transformation

> M(ρ) = (1 − R) ρ (1 − R) + R ρ R .

As R is an orthogonal projector, it is easy to show that || M(ρ) ||<sub>2</sub> ≤ || ρ ||<sub>2</sub> . This is because we may represent ρ as matrix in a basis consisting of the eigenvectors of R; if we divide ρ into block according to rows/columns representing vectors in the image or the kernel of R, the effect of the map M is to set the non-diagonal blocks to zero.

I am interested in how the map M may similarly affect the operator 2 norm of reduced operators on ℂ<sup>A</sup> ⊗ ℂ<sup>B</sup>. So I would like to know:

Is it also true that || tr<sub>C</sub>( M(ρ) ) ||<sub>2</sub> ≤ || tr<sub>C</sub>(ρ) ||<sub>2</sub>  —  where tr<sub>C</sub> is the trace operator acting on ℂ<sup>C</sup>, taken in tensor product with 1<sub>ℂ<sup>A</sup></sub> ⊗ 1<sub>ℂ<sup>B</sup></sub> ?

Comment: To clarify, what precisely is the trace operator on $\mathbb{C}^{C}$? Do you mean the trace on $M_{|C|}(\mathbb{C})$? If so, is this trace normalized so that the trace of the identity in $M_{|C|}(\mathbb{C})$ is 1?

Comment: @Jon Bannon: close... it maps any rank-1 projector to 1. That is to say, it is the first-year-university trace operation, concieved as a positive map $\mathop{tr}:M_{∣C∣}(\mathbb C) \to M_1(\mathbb C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it turns out in retrospect that the problem is trivial. The answer is "no": such a bound does not hold in general.

A simple counterexample is yielded by taking A=1 (so that we effectively deal with ℂ<sup>B</sup> ⊗ ℂ<sup>C</sup> throughout), B=C=2, and taking

> P = ½ **ψ****ψ***  where **ψ** = **e**<sub>1</sub> ⊗ **e**<sub>2</sub> − **e**<sub>2</sub> ⊗ **e**<sub>1</sub>

for standard basis vectors **e**<sub>j</sub> for ℂ<sup>2</sup>. Note that P is the projector onto the antisymmetric subspace of ℂ<sup>B</sup> ⊗ ℂ<sup>C</sup>. The map M may then be re-presented as

> M(ρ) = ½ ρ + ½ UρU*   where U = 1<sub>ℂ<sup>B</sup></sub> ⊗ 1<sub>ℂ<sup>C</sup></sub> − 2P.

The operator U is unitary, and has the effect of 'swapping' the two spaces B and C; that is, for all tensor products **α** ⊗ **β** , we have U(**α** ⊗ **β**) = **β** ⊗ **α** . We may then construct an operator ρ for which the desired bound does not hold, by taking a tensor product of an operator with low 2-norm with one of high 2-norm, e.g.

> ρ = 1<sub>ℂ<sup>B</sup></sub> ⊗ **e**<sub>1</sub>**e**<sub>1</sub>*.

We then have tr<sub>C</sub>(ρ) = 1<sub>ℂ<sup>B</sup></sub> , which has a 2-norm of $\sqrt 2$ ; and tr<sub>C</sub>(UρU*) = 2 **e**<sub>1</sub>**e**<sub>1</sub>*, which has a 2-norm of $2$. By the convexity of the 2-norm, we may then show that 
|| tr<sub>C</sub>( M(ρ) ) ||<sub>2</sub> > || tr<sub>C</sub>(ρ) ||<sub>2</sub> for this choice of P and ρ. A similar construction can be made for any B=C>1, and letting P be the projector onto the antisymmetric space of ℂ<sup>B</sup> ⊗ ℂ<sup>C</sup> .

I'm interested now in what upper bounds may be obtained for || tr<sub>C</sub>( M(ρ) ) ||<sub>2</sub> − || tr<sub>C</sub>(ρ) ||<sub>2</sub> , or related quantities, in the case that P is a rank-1 projector on ℂ<sup>B</sup> ⊗ ℂ<sup>C</sup> . If anyone can show such an interesting such bound, I may 'accept' it; but for the meantime, this answers my original question.